# Is it possible to share SSL certificates across servers?

Tags: https, security-certificate

We have a web application we will be launching soonish and for right now we just have one SSL/HTTPS certificate. We have this one certificate shared across 3 servers(in a cluster for load balancing) which we've been told is "not the right way"...

So do you always have to buy N certificates for N servers or is there a special "shared" certificate or such? Why is it not right to share the certificate when these 3 servers are exactly the same hardware and software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this question:

https://serverfault.com/questions/68753/does-each-server-behind-a-load-balancer-need-their-own-ssl-certificate

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use same SSL Certificate in the different server, if they are serving for a single domain. Like in IIS server, once you configure the SSL. They provide a SSL configure export option, and once you export the configure file you can upload the same file in similar and related server.

Answer (score 0):

I googled your question and got this forum to be useful for this question
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/winservergen/thread/41dcf6f0-06a7-4722-af70-cd73849e6a40